# python SimpleHTTPServer error on module object has no attribute b64decode

Tags: python

I got the following error and I have no idea what's happening. any ideas? thanks

```
  python -m SimpleHTTPServer
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
        exec code in run_globals
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 16, in <module>
        import urllib
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 30, in <module>
        import base64
      File "base64.py", line 7, in <module>
        print (base64.b64decode(cookie))
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'b64decode'
```

Comment: Do you have a file 'base64.py' in your project folder ? If so rename it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a local copy of a file named `base64.py`.  Here are the last few lines of your error output:

```
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 30, in <module>
        import base64
      File "base64.py", line 7, in <module>
        print (base64.b64decode(cookie))
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'b64decode'
```

Note the two filenames.  `urllib.py` has a full path into the python library.  `base64.py` has no path so is in the current directory (ie, likely your project directory).

So, you will need to rename your file to something other than `base64.py`